# how to set different font for different screen size, such as iPhone 6s and iPhone SE

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am making a information collection view for my project, I need to indicate a timer inside. 
How can I set different font size for different screen?
Basically, I want to set the font size to 46 in iPhone 6s and the font size is supposed to be 38 in iPhone SE.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If someone is down-voting or closing this post, then please provide a link where the OP can refer to.

Comment: How is the size computed? Is there a direct relationship to screen width or height? What about landscape mode? What about a 6 Plus? What about iPads? You'll find out you need to answer these questions first before you can pick the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Macros such as this one that determines that the phone size is 4 or 5:

```
#define is4sOr5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height <= 568.0) ? TRUE:FALSE

//This one does IPAD
 label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ? 12 : 10) weight:.2];
//this one uses MACRO 
 label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:(is4sOr5 ? 12 : 10) weight:.2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the interface builder, if you go to the atrributes inspector of your label, use the '+' symbol next the font and set the font for the different size classes.

[image]

Comment: I did try it, but when i switch different devices, i still does not work. And iphone 6s and iphone se are both wC hR

Comment: Size classes are same for all iphone types. Size classes is to determine between iphone and ipad, and in portrait and landscape modes.

Comment: Thanks, it make sense then